# Running node.js server on Linux CentOs

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, centos

Just installed node.js on my new VPS. I created a simple script server.js that is currently running on port 8080, script is located in var/www/html/. The problem is that when I'm trying to access my domain, it shows my default apache page. What should I do to configure my node properly?

Thanks

Script Example:

```
sys = require("sys"),
my_http = require("http");
my_http.createServer(function(request,response){
    sys.puts("I got kicked");
response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8080);
sys.puts("Server Running on 8080");
```

Comment: netstat -natp | grep ":8080" what is the output? also run lsof -p <pid>

Comment: is Apache running on your box?

Comment: How do you start your node app?

Answer (score 1):

Go you your domain on port 8080:

For example: `http://www.myDomain.com:8080`

Comment: I'm quite new but not that new, it's just not responding to my request.

Comment: @Ervin: Is a firewall blocking port 8080?

Answer (score 1):

var/www is the default location for all files to be served by Apache.  Essentially, Apache is "listening" for requests under this directory.  Move your node file to another directory and run it from there.

Comment: I've moved my file to var/node/server.js, still not responding.

Comment: try moving the file out of the /var directory all together.  I can get your script to work from my Documents folder.